# Supporting additional Uri Schemas for the Image.Source property

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

Is there a way to make the following code behind expression to evaluate to true given the Xaml below. I'm asking this question because I have to work with a Library that converts FlowDocuments containing Images to HTML. Only the "Source" Attribute of the Image Control is persisted and you can't use the standard approach of using a BitmapImage because this won't convert back to a Uri String.

```
Debug.Assert(this.image1.Source.ToString() == "data:image/x-png .. <rest of the Image.Source Property below>")

<Image x:Name="image1" Source="data:image/x-png;base64,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"></Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to implement a pluggable protocol for the "data" Scheme. This way the Source property acts exactly as with the built-in protocols for Image retrieval. The technique is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f6c88af.aspx).

Comment: Can you post little more details of how to do this?